# Llenar un select a partir de otro select con php, mysql y jquery TENGO ERROR ajax - php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Editado:

En este pedazo de código: donde dice data: se supone que ese id, el nombre que le di yo a la variable es la que le envió a php, pero a la hora de recibirla en php con $_POST["id"], me dice que está variable no existe por ningún lado, el problema es que pues se supone que el debería reconocer esa variable en php como he visto en videos y otros códigos, pero esa variable id que cree en ajax en data no llega a php

```
var id = $('#lista1').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: {id: id}, //acá debería enviarse está variable id y ser
                                  reconocida en php, pero no existe para php 
success: function(r){
                    $('#select2lista').html(r);
                    console.log(id);
                }
            });
```

el error qué me sale: Warning: Undefined array key "id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba2\index.php on line 47

siempre y siempre, en teoría se la estoy enviando, llamada (id); ya probé de distintas maneras y ninguna envía, me estoy volviendo loco :c

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <select name="lista1" id="lista1">
        <option value="0">Selecciona: </option>
        <option value="1">UWU1</option>
        <option value="2">UWU2</option>
        <option value="3">UWU3</option>
        <option value="4">UWU4</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div class="select2lista"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            recargarLista();
            $('#lista1').change(function(){
                recargarLista(); 
            });
        })

        function recargarLista(){
            var id = $('#lista1').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: {id: id},
                success: function(r){
                    $('#select2lista').html(r);
                    console.log(id);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <?php
        //acá intento mostrarla pero no sirve, ya sea aquí o un archivo externo.
        echo "dato: " . $_POST["id"];

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: vale vale, que pena, ahora mismo lo hare.

Comment: ahí intente explicarlo un poco mejor creó jeje, es que mi problema es que esa variable id que creo en data en ajax llamada (id), esa variable debería ser reconocida en php cuando le hago el llamada con $_POST["id"], pero no existe, por ningún lado, vi en varios videos que así se hace, pero a ellos les sirve, pero no se porque a mi no, en este momento solo quiero que me reconozca la variable php, no estoy haciendo llamados de sql todavía.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a hacer un console.log(); o un alert de la variable id?
Creo que para los select tienes que especificar que quieres el value del que está seleccionado. Sería algo así

```
var id = $('#lista1').filter(':selected').val();
```

Comment: dejame intentarlo.

Comment: el dato existe, me muestra el dato id cuando le hago con el console.log, pero a la hora de buscar esta variable en php con $_POST[] no existe.

Comment: ahí intente explicarlo un poco mejor creó, es que mi problema es que esa variable id que creo en data en ajax llamada (id), esa variable debería ser reconocida en php cuando le hago el llamada con $_POST["id"], pero no existe, por ningún lado, vi en varios videos que así se hace, pero a ellos les sirve, pero no se porque a mi no, en este momento solo quiero que me reconozca la variable php, no estoy haciendo llamados de sql todavía.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a poner en tu código PHP la siguiente línea a ver si te está llegando algún dado.

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_REQUEST, true).'</pre>';
```

También cuando haces la llamada ajax si tienes en el navegador la consola de desarrollo abierta, en la pestaña de red puedes seleccionar la llamada ajax y mirar las variables que le estás enviando al servidor. Así descartamos si no se están enviando por JS o si no las está recibiendo por PHP.

Comment: Efectivamente algo llega, pero si pongo un botón y llega el dato que esta en name="lista1", pero la variable que cree en ajax para pasarle esa a  php no existe, y también esta el dato, lo puedo ver en consola, pero la variable que creo en ajax llamada id, cuando la busco en php con $_POST["id"] no existe por ningún lado, qué pena hacerte tomas el tiempo de responder esto ajaj, me estoy volviendo loco jaja